# Exception thrown while executing UI block: Invalid Region <center: +37.33233141, -122.03121860, span: +0.04491556, -5.73770224>

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm building an app with `react-native-maps`. In testing, I've got it set up with a button that toggles between two different locations (DC and Concord NH), one of which happens to be my actual current location. I also have a "Find me!" button to go to the current location.

On the Android simulator, when I hit "find me" it jumps to San Fransisco, which I assume is where the simulator location is set. I don't own an actual Android device

On both iOS simulator and on my iPhone, the DC/NH buttons work, and on my iPhone when I've toggled into DC, I see my blue dot. However, on both the iOS simulator and my iPhone, when I hit "find me" I get this error (the coordinates below are when running on the simulator:

```
Exception thrown while executing UI block:
Invalid Region <center: +37.33233141, -122.03121860, span: +0.04491556, -5.73770224>
```

The same error happens, sensibly with different coords, on my iPhone.

It appears that Android and iOS are translating the coordinates differently, or something like that. They both read the coords I give for DC and NH the same, and appear to show the same region when I call those locations up.

By the way, I'm using Apple Maps on iOS – not ready to do the whole ejecting code thing to use Google Maps.

Here's the code I use to get the current location and convert it to numbers that React Native can understand correctly:

```js
 calculateRegion(latitude, longitude, accuracy) {
    const oneDegreeOfLongitudeInMeters = 111.32;
    const circumference = 40075 / 360;
    const latitudeDelta = accuracy / oneDegreeOfLongitudeInMeters;
    const longitudeDelta = accuracy * (1 / Math.cos(latitude * circumference));
    const region = { latitude, longitude, latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta };
    this.setState({ region });
  }

  getLocation = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const long = position.coords.longitude;
      const accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
      this.calculateRegion(lat, long, accuracy);
    });
  };
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Instead of doing setState you may set or update region by using "this". Like this.region=region. If the problem continues can you post your code?